# Running executables on nfs with "./" command

Tags: nfs, pbs

I have a small cluster system running on Centos 7. I've setup nfs and pbs pro to run jobs on parallel. While everything was working smoothly, I guessed, at some point, I messed up something. Thus, some of the nodes stopped running jobs and started giving errors such as "permission denied" for the executables. Executable file is located inside the nfs directory. I tried to run the executable specifically on that problematic node. But it does not run with "./executable_file" command. However, it can be executed with "bash executable_file" command. Other slave nodes can execute the file with "./" and "bash" command without any issue. So, I assume this may be the reason my jobs are failing on that specific node. Would appreciate it if someone tell me how to set up/mount nfs with running executables with "./" .

Comment: How is your NFS filesystem mounted on each of the nodes? You will get permission denied if your filesystem was mounted with `noexec` for example. Please update your question to include the output of `mount` on the problematic node(s).

Comment: Thanks, @Steve for your help. I found the solution. I am answering my question so that It could help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I checked the /etc/mtab file, I noticed "noexec" inside it. I removed mtab file and then unmount and remounted NFS directory. As a last step, /etc/fstab is updated with "exec" and mounted again with mount-a without restarting the node.